# Can the re-occurring of 404 error lead to Internal server error (500)?

Tags: http-status-code-404, 500-error

I'm wondering can the re-occurring of `File Not Found` (404) error eventually lead to `Internal server error` (500)?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What web server? Are you talking about a looping 404? Did a backend service crash? Do you have any relevant logs?

Comment: Its just a general question. I have had some experience using `Apache` and `Litespeed`. I just want to know if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely argue it is possible if your 404 page was built using a dynamic language like PHP, ASP, etc. (anything beyond what is considered just markup language). The introduction of a dynamic language introduces a wealth of ways in which a page can fail (threading problems, memory management problems, resource locking problems, etc.)...some of which become evident one a single page load and others that are only evident under tremendous stress.